# Run a block of legacy code in compliance with an older Ruby language version

Tags: ruby, jruby, rubymine

I wasn't sure what to title this question, so if you wan't to change it, be my guest.

I am wondering if there is some way to run a block of Ruby code in compliance with a previos version of the ruby language. It would essentially be some sort of 'compatability mode' but only for a block of code.

My idea was to chagne the RUBY_VERSION global variable, and see if Ruby then behaved as it would in that version, but this seems to do nothing. Here is my attempt:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION

an_object = Time.now

an_object.tap do |o|
  puts 'in tep function'
end # ===> an_object

RUBY_VERSION = 1.7 #potentially change ruby version to an older version to run legacy code

#attempt to run a function that was not available in version 1.7, (just an example)
an_object.tap do |o|
  puts 'in tep function'
end # ===> an_object

puts RUBY_VERSION
```

I realize that I could code a conditional, and test the current version of Ruby, and then execute code based on the results of that test, but that doesn't fit my needs, and it would be better to just re-factor all of our unit tests and acceptance tests if it came down to this.

Comment: I think the only sustainable solution to this is to port the code to the newer Ruby version you are currently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple rubies installed on your system, for example with `rbenv`:

```
ls -l ~/.rbenv/versions/
drwxr-xr-x  5 jared  staff  170 Nov  7 13:59 1.8.7-p374
drwxr-xr-x  6 jared  staff  204 Oct 31 15:02 2.1.1
drwxr-xr-x  6 jared  staff  204 Oct 30 12:19 2.1.2
drwxr-xr-x  6 jared  staff  204 Oct 30 12:03 2.1.4
```

.. then **you can "shell out" from the newer ruby** to the older ruby.  I recommend using [Open3.popen3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) for this, but there are simpler methods, like [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-system).

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
$ irb
irb(main):002:0> ruby = "/Users/jared/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby"
irb(main):016:0> Open3.popen3(ruby) { |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
irb(main):017:1*   stdin.puts "puts RUBY_VERSION"
irb(main):018:1>   stdin.close
irb(main):019:1>   puts stdout.read
irb(main):020:1> }
1.8.7
=> nil
```

How to get your "old ruby" code as a string is left as an exercise to the reader.  Maybe try [Method#source_location](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Method.html#method-i-source_location)?

Another challenge will be how to return objects from the "old ruby".  Serializing with YAML is one option.

**However**, I agree with @p11y that "the only sustainable solution to this is to port the code to the newer Ruby".

Comment: Well this will certainly work, but I don't think I will use it. I completely agree that refactoring the code is the correct path.

Comment: Good :)  You'll be happier in the long run, and your ops team will thank you for not depending on two rubies!

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of Ruby only support a single version of the language. For example, YARV 2.1.4 only supports Ruby 2.1.4, MRI 1.8.7 only supports Ruby 1.8.7, and so on.

JRuby, IronRuby and Rubinius did at one time or another support multiple versions of Ruby (this was during the transitional period from Ruby 1.8 to Ruby 1.9), however most of them have removed this capability.

And even then, they only supported one single version per interpreter instance.

Answer (score 0):

The [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem might be what you're looking for. From the README:

> The goal of 'backports' is to make it easier to write ruby code that runs across different versions of Ruby.
>
> For example, if you want to use flat_map, even in Ruby implementations that don't include it, as well as the new bsearch method:

```
require 'backports/1.9.2/enumerable/flat_map'
require 'backports/2.0.0/array/bsearch'
```

> This will enable Enumerable#flat_map and Array#bsearch, using the native versions if available or otherwise provide a pure Ruby version.

Also, you can always ask a Ruby object what it knows how to do, either by scanning its list of [`methods`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Object.html#method-i-methods), or using [`respond_to?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F). If it doesn't know how to do something, then you can supply an equivalent method. Your equivalent might be a pure-Ruby solution which runs more slowly, but gets the job done and at least functionality is maintained. If you later run on a more recent Ruby that has the compiled code, then you gain the speed.